# Unix Time stamp day of the week pattern

Tags: unix-timestamp

If all I have is the unix timestamp and I am not able to use any functions to format it (such as day of the week or date) is there any known pattern by looking at the timestamp to deduce what day of the week it is?

for example perhaps all timestamps that are divisible by 150 are Mondays

Comment: don't forget about leap years!

Comment: @DanielA.White: Actually, for this particular problem, *do* forget about leap years. The unix timestamp is a count of seconds, and each week is 2073600 seconds long.  The day-of-week cycle is independent of months and years. Now if you want to know the day of the week in local time, you need to account for DST transitions (which you can't reasonably handle without library functions).

Comment: Is there some reason you're not able to use library functions? Also, do you want the day of the week in UTC or in local time? (The latter is going to be a lot more difficult).

Answer (score 2):

- [The Unix Epoch (Jan 1, 1970, 00:00)](http://currentmillis.com/?0) was on a Thursday. Specifically it marked the beginning of a Thursday.
- [The first Monday after the Unix Epoch](http://currentmillis.com/?345600000) begins on Jan 5, 1970, 00:00. This is a UNIX timestamp of 96 hours.
- [The second Monday after the Unix Epoch](http://currentmillis.com/?950400000) begins on Jan 12, 1970, 00:00. This is a UNIX timestamp of 264 hours.

Let's assume X is your Unix timestamp in hours. The formula `((X - 96) % (264 - 96)) / 24` will return a zero-based weekday index where 0 is Monday and 6 is Sunday. The formula looks like this:

- `(X - 96) % 168 / 24` (if X is your timestamp in hours)
- `(X - 345600) % 604800 / 86400` (if X is your timestamp in seconds)
- `(X - 345600000) % 604800000 / 86400000` (if X is your timestamp in milliseconds)

If i experiment with exactly this moment, defined by a Unix timestamp of 1466710873523 ms i would get `(1466710873523 - 345600000) % 604800000 / 86400000` which is ~3.8 (meaning it's Thursday) (almost Friday though :). Note though that it's Thursday UTC - in certain timezones it might be different so for local time you would need to take timezone offset into account.

Answer (score 0):

From my own observations, the timestamp at midnight GMT ends in 000 every 6 days. The sequence is as follows: 000, 400, 800, 200, 600, 000, 400, 800, 200...
So, today (in UCT) started at 1465948**800** and has been Wednesday. 
So I know that that tomorrow's starting timestamp will end with 200 etc.

If you count the days from today (1465948**800**) to your desired date and divide by 6, 
if the remainder is 1, the ending will be '200', 
2: '600', 
3: '000', 
4: '400', 
5: '800'.

Because a week has 7 days, if this Wednesday ended in 800, next Wednesday will end in 200 and the following wednesday in 600, etc.